# react-responsive-carousel messed up

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, carousel

I've read the documentation, I don't know why it's working but it's messed up. Here's my code :

```
function CarouselItem(props) {
  const { post } = props

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <img src={`http://localhost:5000/image/${post.foto}`} />
        <p className="legend">{post.judul}</p>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

function NewsItem(props) {
  const { posts } = props.post

  let content = posts.map(item => <CarouselItem key={item._id} post={item} />)

  return (
    <div>
      <Carousel showThumbs={false}>{content}</Carousel>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It turns out like this :

[image]

Comment: did you import the CSS for react response carousel?

Comment: woopsie, silly me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this in the first line of your `.js` file:

```
import 'react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css';
```